# No menus being displayed in SideBar First

Tags: theming

Im using my own Omega 3 sub-theme and a new superfish menu (I created) to be displayed in the Sidebar First section of each page...no big deal. The menu displays as needed in while Im admin, but the entire sidebar is gone when viewed as anonymous. Thinking it may be an issue with Superfish I disabled the new menu and added the standard navigation menu in its place...same issue.

I kept debugging and noticed a weird issue Ive never seen: no menus are working as blocks in the first sidebar. I can add a static block with simple text or content in it and the sidebar is displayed as needed, but never functions if a menu is the only content in the section.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Menu works on the sidebar.

For your case, it's definitely the 'Permission' issue.

Permission for menu items: For example, you have only 'Add Content' item in the Navigation Menu. When you are logged in as an admin you have that menu on the sidebar as you have the permission to add a content. To display this item to authenticated/anonymous users you have to configure permission from 'Admin Menu' > 'People' > 'Permission'. Please check the permission of your menu items and configure as required.

Permission for Blocks: By default menu blocks have no permission restriction. Please check your menu block's permission section from 'Admin Menu' > 'Structure' > 'Blocks' > 'Edit' the specific block > 'Permission' tab at the bottom.

I hope it will help you.